# Android: Working, simple example of using jcifs to access a windows share

Tags: android, jcifs

Does anyone have a simple (preferably), comfirmed working example of connecting to a windows share using jcifs in Android? I realize it's a very basic question, but I have been trying everything I could find (which isn't very much) on the net without really getting anywhere. Either the examples are for "normal" Java, which makes my Android app crash with messages like "cannot find a class which is definetely imported in the jcifs jar". Or they are huge, complex and with lots of extra funcitonality - and they don't work when I try using them in my project(s).

I just want to:
- Implement jcifs (I know how to import it, of course, but I don't trust that it actually works)
- Create a connection to a windows share (preferably using just IP address, username and password)
- Read a file or a directory on the share
- Download a file
- Upload a file

One thing at a time, so that I can go through each function and learn how it works. Anyone? A "huge" project that can be imported is also a possibility, of course - then I can try to pick it apart. But I haven't found anything which I'm able to get working yet.

Comment: You are trying to an intranet library for an Android app or baking it into a custom ROM?

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I don't understand your question (kind of a newbie here). I'm trying to make a straight app that connects to a cifs/smb share, and I'm having problems getting a simple example using jcifs to work.

Comment: Have you tried this site: http://learn-it-stuff.blogspot.com/2012/01/adding-jcifs-api-to-our-android-java.html

Comment: Yep, I tried that a while ago, and the code has so many errors that there has to be a shitload of things that guy didn't bother to include.

Comment: And have you tried this one: http://code.google.com/p/sambaexplorer/

Comment: Hey, that one I didn't find. Thanks - I'll take a look at it and see if I'm able to deduce something from it :-)